# How can I convert Stream to IntStream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I want to implement a static method called `youngWinners` that given a `Stream<Winner>` returns a `new Stream<Winner>` containing the winners that are younger than 35, ordered alphabetically.

Inside my file I have : index, year, age, name, movie.

My problem is that I don't know how I can convert `Stream` into `IntStream` to compare the age with 35. I also got a bit confused, do I have to use comparators to do this or not ?

```
public static Stream<Winner> youngWinners(Stream<Winner> young) {
    //  Stream<Winner> youngWin = young;
    String[] toString = young.toArray(s -> new String[s]);
    Arrays.stream(toString).flatMap((<any> f) -> {
        try {
            return Files.lines(Paths.get(f))
                    .filter(age -> int (age) <= 35 )
                    .mapToInt(a -> a.getWinnerage())
                    .map(WinneropsDB::new);                                                    
        } catch (Exception e) {                
            System.out.println("error");
            return null;
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your Winner class should implement Comparable, your implemented compareTo method should compare names, you can use regular .stream() method to get a stream of your Winners array/collection, call .filter() to get people older than 35 then call sort() it will implement your compareTo implicitly and finally print out results. Also your code is ugly, I'm sorry I just wanted to say it :D, but you'll get better, don't give up.

Comment: because i am a beginner in java and i do not have any experience in java :D

Comment: but  i try to do better ;-)

Comment: could you help me how can i make my code beautiful ?

Comment: There will never be a good result, if you don’t understand your task. That’s the failure reason #1 for projects, the lack of a precise definition of the goal. So as long as you don’t even know whether your input is a `Stream<Winner>` or something containing file names, you won’t get anywhere.

Comment: i just try learn java programming with my professors questions. anything that i did is searchin on the web and study because i do not have more time. But i really interested to learn in a correct way. could you tell me how can i learn java better? thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't need an `IntStream` at all.

Simply do:

```
return young.filter(w -> w.getAge() < 35)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Winner::getName));
```

Comment: maybe i do not understand verry well the meaning of stream.anyway thank you :-)